# Can we edit managed package Permission set Groups in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, permissions, permission-sets, system-permissions, permission-set-groups

I have a permission set group and need to edit it, but there is no edit option available, Is there any workaround/idea for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Packaged Permission Set Groups have some editability in the subscriber org, as covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm#mdc_permission_set_groups):

|  | Support |
| --- | --- |
| Component Is Updated During Package Upgrade | Yes |
| Subscriber Can Delete Component From Org | No |
| Package Developer Can Remove Component From Package | No |
| Component Has IP Protection | No |

**Editable Properties After Package Promotion or Installation**

Only Package Developer Can Edit

- None

Both Package Developer and Subscriber Can Edit

- Permission Set Group Components (Developer can add and remove while Subscriber can add)

Neither Package Developer or Subscriber Can Edit

- None

---

If this isn't enough, consider cloning or creating your own equivalent Perm Set Group.